# Can numpy strides stride only within subarrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, stride

I have a really big numpy array(145000 rows * 550 cols). And I wanted to create rolling slices within subarrays. I tried to implement it with a function. The function `lagged_vals` behaves as expected but `np.lib.stride_tricks` does not behave the way I want it to -

```
def lagged_vals(series,l):
# Garbage implementation but still right
    return np.concatenate([[x[i:i+l] for i in range(x.shape[0]) if i+l <= x.shape[0]] for x in series]
                          ,axis = 0)

# Sample 2D numpy array
something = np.array([[1,2,2,3],[2,2,3,3]])
lagged_vals(something,2) # Works as expected

# array([[1, 2],
#     [2, 2],
#     [2, 3],
#     [2, 2],
#     [2, 3],
#     [3, 3]])


np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(something,
                               (something.shape[0]*something.shape[1],2),
                               (8,8))

# array([[1, 2],
#        [2, 2],
#        [2, 3],
#        [3, 2], <--- across subarray stride, which I do not want
#        [2, 2],
#        [2, 3],
#        [3, 3])
```

How do I remove that particular row in the `np.lib.stride_tricks` implementation? And how can I scale this cross array stride removal for a big numpy array ?

Comment: So, would you be okay with a 3D output of those strides, or do you have to have 2D output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's possible with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides). Here's one way -

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

L = 2 # window length
shp = a.shape
strd = a.strides

out_shp = shp[0],shp[1]-L+1,L
out_strd = strd + (strd[1],)

out = as_strided(a, out_shp, out_strd).reshape(-1,L)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [177]: a
Out[177]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

In [178]: out
Out[178]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6],
       [6, 7]])
```

Note that the last step of reshaping forces it to make a copy there. But that's can't be avoided if we need the final output to be a `2D`. If we are okay with a `3D` output, skip that reshape and thus achieve a `view`, as shown with the sample case -

```
In [181]: np.shares_memory(a, out)
Out[181]: False

In [182]: as_strided(a, out_shp, out_strd)
Out[182]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [5, 6],
        [6, 7]]])

In [183]: np.shares_memory(a, as_strided(a, out_shp, out_strd) )
Out[183]: True
```

Comment: Thanks! Tested and upvoted! Cheers!! I prefer it to be 2D.